# Is it possible to recreate a dSYM file in IOS?

Tags: ios

If the original dSYM file is lost, and it is also not available in xCode organizer and iTunes Connect (we have a custom build workflow that did not upload dSYMs to iTunes Connect), is it possible to recreate it from command line? We tried to build from the exact same codebase but the dSYM came out has a different UUID.

Answer (score 3):

Long story short, I am afraid you are not able to reproduce.

dSYMs are produced per build. And they does not change unless a Bitcode enabled build has been released. When a Bitcode enabled build is released, Apple generates a new dSYMs which can be downloaded from App Store Connect.

Ideally, they are found at either machine's local when build by `Xcode GUI` or invoking `xcodebuild`, or at App Store Connect if Bitcode is enabled. You said you already checked those options so I am not going to explain those. I don't think you'd skip but just to notice, if you are using Sentry, Crashlytics or any crash reporting tool, chances are highly that dSYMs are provided to them. If you are using such a tool and haven't check yet, I would surely check those option as well.

Lastly, based on your explanation, I assume you are using CD to deliver your build. If this is the case, I would suggest running this CLI command to double check that they aren't present on the machine you use to take build.

```
mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == <UUID>"
```

Hope you are just missing a slight point and I could help you figure that out.

Please ask me or correct me if I am skipping or mistaken at a point.

Good luck and cheers!